# Sharing tab 'can add' permission for folderish archetype does not seem to work properly

Tags: plone, archetypes

I developed a custom folderish content-type in plone 4; in the xml file that specifies the profile of this content type I defined some other content types objects as addable to this folderish as contents. In the `rolemap.xml` file I have the following settings:

```
<permission name="my permission" acquire="False">
  <role name="Manager" />
  <role name="Owner" />
</permission>
```

The same settings apply for the allowed 'children' content types.

So in general I don't want anyone but the owner (and the administrator of course) to be able to edit the object. What I guess the owner could do is to explicitly delegate permission on his object through the 'sharing' tab. But when the owner grants the 'can add' and 'can edit' permission to another user, when this other user logs in, he can edit the folderish object, but can't add items inside, as the 'Add new' menu does not show, and this is not just a UI problem, e.g. when he calls the URL

```
http://<myhost>/<mysite>/<myfolderishobject>/createObject?type_name=<myallowedType>
```

the option for adding an object inside the form shows up, but when he submits it he gets an 'insufficient privilege' message.

A couple of additional observations: Both the owner of the folderish and the delegated user belong to the same group, and things don't change if I set the 'acquire' attribute in rolemap to True.

I wonder if the problem is in my configuration or caused by a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Plone uses a [role-based security model](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions/permissions-and-roles), have a look at it first, it will explain the following.
When on the sharing tab you give a user the 'can add' permission, in fact what you really do is give him the `Contributor` role. So in short, for this to work with your content type you would have to allow anyone with the contributor role to add, i.e.

```
<permission name="my permission" acquire="False">
  <role name="Manager" />
  <role name="Owner" />
  <role name="Contributor" />      
</permission>
```

Be aware that other users might acquire the `Contributor` role from higher level folders too.

Comment: the problem if I apply these settings is that an user granted with the 'add' permission on the parent folder containing these folderish objects, can add children objects to any folderish created into the parent folder (even if he can't edit the container), regardless if the owner granted explicitly this permission or not, and I don't want this behavior

Comment: maybe I should uncheck the 'inehrit permission' on the parent folder...but this doens't seem to work, at least for already created objects

Comment: ok, I checked better, the problem is that by default Plone enables the checkbox 'inherit permissions from higher level', and if the owner of the folderish doesn't want contributors of the parent folder being able to add children elements to his folderish, he has to uncheck this box; of course I can't pretend users of my portal to understand they have to do this, so I wonder if there is a way to default that checkbox to unchecked...

Comment: probably the easyest solution could be disable the permission inheritance at the moment of object creation programmatically, but I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in order to avoid that others could acquire the contributor role from parent folders, the solution is adding the following line of code:
self.**ac_local_roles_block** = True

before reindexing object security on the folderish object itself